# Upgrade problem

Tags: upgrade, 12.10

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade:

```bash
The package 'unity' is marked for removal but it is in the removal blacklist. 

This can be caused by: 

* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.
```

What shall i do? Do i need to remove untiy from blacklist but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
update manager -d
```

**Option 2:**

```
Step 1: Install Gnome
Step 2: Log in Through Gnome
Step 3: Uninstall unity using Synaptic
Step 4: Try upgrade
```